# Dynamically create OBJECTS NAME in javascript/jquery, NOT it's keys or values

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you create an object with a dynamically created NAME?
NOT dynamically created keys or values.
I'd like to learn this in both jQuery and javascript

```
var com = "thing_"
var bined = "one"
var [com+bined] = {}

//so I can populate as such:
thing_one.key = value
```

I've googled my eyes out and tried a thousand things. Thanks in advance and apologies if I overlooked the obvious.

UPDATE:
I accepted BadPiggie answer, as it does function as requested, however, I agree with Teemu and Terry's comments: this is not necessary and doesn't really have a use case.

It was fun to explore, thanks for all your input!

Comment: JS doesn't have a concept for dynamic variable names.

Comment: This also feels like an XY problem. There’s really no use case of a dynamically generated global variable name.

Comment: Teemu and Terry, I really appreciate your input. I am also looking at different ways to achieve the desired outcome. However, I still wanted to explore this as a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript ***(In browser)*** `global variables` are property of `window` object. So you can do like this.

```js
var com = "thing_"
var bined = "one"
window[com+bined] = {}

//you can populate as such:
thing_one.key = "some value";

console.log(thing_one);
```

Or you can use `eval()` but **Not Recommended**

```js
var com = "thing_"
var bined = "one"
eval(`var ${com + bined} = {}`);

//you can populate as such:
thing_one.key = "some value";

console.log(thing_one);
```

Comment: BadPiggie, Thank you for this! I has used the wrong quotes. when I tested eval :-( Your version works. I was strongly discouraged from using window[], so I was looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference another object to stick your object in.  If you did this in a class, you could do this[com+bined]={}.  Outside of a class, you could do window[com+bined]={}.